# How can I use a value from third table in merge's insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My merge statement looks like:

```
MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
USING SourceProducts    AS Source
ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price, Testvalue) 
    VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price, (select value from testtable where id=source.ProductID)

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        Target.ProductName  = Source.ProductName,
        Target.Price        = Source.Price
Target.testvalue=(Select value from testtable where id=source.ProductID)
```

Is there any way to do the above. That is - use the value from another table.

Comment: Have you tried using a _derived table_ that joins your two tables as `Source`?

Comment: It seems that you haven't received any answers worth accepting on your last 20 questions. Perhaps you could provide some feedback about why the suggestions and answers don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify a query as your source, not only a table

e.g.:

```
MERGE TargetProducts AS Target
USING ( 
        SELECT   s.ProductID,s.ProductName, s.Price  , t.Testvalue      
        FROM SourceProducts s
        JOIN testtable t
            ON t.id = s.ProductId 
        )AS Source
ON Source.ProductID = Target.ProductID

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (ProductID,ProductName, Price,Testvalue) 
    VALUES (Source.ProductID,Source.ProductName, Source.Price, Source.Testvalue)

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        Target.ProductName  = Source.ProductName,
        Target.Price        = Source.Price,
        Target.testvalue    = Source.Testvalue;
```

Comment: Aside: A `left outer join` might be applicable if there aren't rows in `testtable` corresponding to all of the rows of interest in `SourceProducts`.